# Adding Google Maps to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I have added the map view inside the `RecyclerView` alongside other types of list items but now ... how and where do I initialize the map, where do I listen for onMapReady so that I can place a marker afterwards, and how do I handle the recycling of the item ?

Any ideas what the best practice is in this situation ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two possible ways, to do this thing,
one is [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) using, which will give you the snapshot of the map.

Another is, you can use `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` inside of recycler item and initialize in your `viewholder` like below,

```
public class AdapterWithMap extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterWithMap.CustomeHolder> {

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CustomeHolder holder, int position)
        {
            GoogleMap thisMap = holder.mapCurrent;
            if(thisMap != null)
                thisMap.moveCamera();//initialize your position with lat long  or move camera
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(CustomeHolder holder)
        {
            // Cleanup MapView here?
            if (holder.mapCurrent != null)
            {
                holder.mapCurrent.clear();
                holder.mapCurrent.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
            }
        }
        public class CustomeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {
            GoogleMap mapCurrent;
            MapView map;

            public CustomeHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                map = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapImageView);
                if (map != null)
                {
                    map.onCreate(null);
                    map.onResume();
                    map.getMapAsync(this);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
                mapCurrent = googleMap;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: this using googlemap v1, then can be removed and not working after android 11

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and load map preview, not map fragment
Like this:

```
    GlideApp
        .with(context)
        .load("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + 
               lat + 
               "," + 
               lng + 
               "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false" +
               "&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%" + 
               markerLat + 
               "," + 
               markerLlng)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(myImageView);
```

Or using lib - [static-maps-api](https://github.com/renaudcerrato/static-maps-api)

Comment: Using static maps are NOT FREE this solution is nice idea but costs some money. thanks anyway

Comment: @AlpAltunel actualy, as you can see, my code not contains any api keys. So you can use it as many times as you want

Comment: yes but if you use like your code after one request it fails and gives 403 error even if you use key or not.

Answer (score 1):

there is something called lite mode in google map you can use in recycler view

check this [litemode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite)

and sample code example [LiteListDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LiteListDemoActivity.java)